# How to convert IDLE python files into a ZIP folder?

Tags: python

I have an assignment which needs me to convert 4 separate py files into a zip folder. Do you guys know how to do this?

This is the part of the instruction which tells me to compress it

Programs: Name your programs, q1.py, q2.py, q3.py, q4.py and submit all as a zip file(named A1_my_upi.zip) to the assignment drop box before the deadline (No late submission
accepted).

I have read on the internet that I have to import zipfile. Can some one please clairfy?

Comment: I just tried doing the normal way by right clicking it and pressing 'send to'. It works but I am not 100% sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that your files are in `/users/matthew/documents/school/assignments/a1`. Here are a couple of ways in which you can do this:

Python:

```
import os
from zipfile import Zipfile

dirpath = '/users/matthew/documents/school/assignments/a1'

with open("A1_my_upi.zip", 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in os.listdir(dirpath):
        if not fname.endswith('.py'):
            continue
        outfile.write(os.path.join(dirpath, fname))
```

Now, you have a `A1_my_upi.zip` that you can submit

If you're on a linux/mac computer, you can do this:

```
$ cd /users/matthew/documents/school/assignments/a1
$ cd ..
$ zip A1_my_upi.zip a1/*.py
```

Now, you have a `A1_my_upi.zip` that you can submit. It exists at `/users/matthew/documents/school/assignments/A1_my_upi.zip`

Comment: I think the question isn't about how to create zip archives with Python, but rather how to submit his assignment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the code I was getting on the internet. If I compress it the normal way, i.e. create new folder -> right click -> then press send to -> compressed folder, would that give the same effect?

Comment: @Matthew: I'm not quite sure. However, you could easily test it by doing so, and emailing the resulting zip file to a friend, and trying open said zip file on your friend's computer - that would be a a pretty sureshot test